# Using enum values for comparison

Tags: c#, enums, comparison

I have a class with `enums` setup like so:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum firstByte : uint
{
    Battery = 4,           
    Reverse = 4
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class class1: PropertyChangedBase
{
    public firstByte FirstByte;
}
```

From another class I would like to use a comparison like:

```
class class2
{    
    uint test = 1;

    if (class1.FirstByte.Battery >= test) {...}
}
```

But I can't really reach `Battery` like that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215954/using-enum-values) is really similar, but it's not exactly the same because his `enum` is not used in an object-oriented manner, like mine. I also used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444013/c-access-enum-from-another-class) for help, but it confuses me because he sets his `enum` property equal to an item from the `enum` type. How do I do something like: `class1.FirstByte.Battery` ?

Comment: Your code does not compile. The enum must be defined outside of the interface. You can define a property on the interface with the enum type.

Comment: Wow, you're right. That was silly. Do i still need to define them in a class though? I get a runtime error when I define the enums outside of the class in the namespace. Probably a rookie mistake as well. I haven't done much work with enums.

Comment: You need to define a method that uses the `Class1` type.

Comment: And do what with it? If you have an answer I'm sure it'll work.

Comment: Do you mean to have two enum FlagAttributes with the same value 4?

Comment: @kmcnamee That was just an example. Basically I'm using enums to mimic bit fields

Comment: Got you sample.  You can remove the 'Attribute' part from the attribute if your in the mood since its an attribute i.e. [Flags] vs [FlagsAttribute] both will work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method on `Class2` that uses the `FirstByte` property. Otherwise `FirstByte` must be marked as `static`.

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum FirstByte : uint
{
    Battery = 4,           
    Reverse = 4
}
```

Use a method with a parameter:

```
public class Class1
{
    public FirstByte FirstByte { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{    
    public bool SomeMethod(Class1 class1)
    {
        uint test = 1;

        return class1.FirstByte >= (FirstByte) test;
    }
}
```

Use a static field when `FirstByte` must be global:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static FirstByte FirstByte { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{    
    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        uint test = 1;

        return Class1.FirstByte >= (FirstByte) test;
    }
}
```